# VS2017 vstemplate automatically install Nuget Package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Hi I have a Nuget Package and want to let it automatically install after project is created.
I added this into my vstemplate file:

```
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages>
      <package id="MyWebVisuDlls" version="1.0.5" />
    </packages>
  </WizardData>
```

It works it adds the Nuget to the Project after I created a new one from template, BUT it does not install the dlls from the Nuget Package. It just gives me a warning that there are unupdated/installed Nuget Packages in the project. And if I click on Update Now the Dlls are getting installed.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I litterly searched a whole day now and besides an own VSIX Project I cant find anything.

Comment: Hi Lukas, looks like you're creating a VS template project. Do you want a scenario like: `Create a new project from my custom template, then this new-created project have some packages installed automatically? `If so, I suggest you can follow the Perry's suggestion, for VS2017, normally these [two options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#enable-and-disable-package-restore-in-visual-studio) are enabled, so we can do what you need by simply modifying your xx.csproj file. If I misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know. We'll try best to help :)

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT and Lnace Li-MSFT . Thanks for your answers. Yes Lance you are right I want this exact szenario. I will try the solution of Perry soon and I will give you updates about it here.

Comment: Package Reference does work yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this automatically? I litterly searched a whole
>   day now and besides an own VSIX Project I cant find anything.

**l am sure that it can be realized.** You can just modify your `projecttemplate.csproj` file and then add the Reference code to these packages. And you need to be clear that when you create a project based on your new template, VS will automatically read `xxx.csproj` and then recover the corresponding nuget package based on the information in it.

**Besides**, it is important to note that nuget packages can be referenced in two ways, `packages.config` and `PackageReference`.(It really depends on which way you want to import the package).

**Solution**

**1)** use **PackageReference**

a) modify ProjectTemplate.csproj(which is in the **Solution Explorer** just like the picture below) and then add this:

[image]

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyWebVisuDlls">
      <Version>1.0.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

b) publish this template and then you can use it.

**2)** use **Packages.config**

a) Create a file called `packages.config` in your project root directory and then add these in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MyWebVisuDlls" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

`TargetFramework` mainly means your framework version of your current project. For me, l created a `net framework 4.7.2 c# project template` project, so I used `net472`.

b) right-click the file and select **Property** and change `Build Action` to `Content`, `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` and then change `Include in VSIX` to `True`.

c) add these files in projecttemplate.csproj as above:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="packages.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap, Version=3.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Charts.v16.1.Core, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Charts.v16.1.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Data.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Office.v16.1.Core, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Office.v16.1.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Printing.v16.1.Core, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Printing.v16.1.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.RichEdit.v16.1.Core, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.RichEdit.v16.1.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Utils.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Utils.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.Resources.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Web.Resources.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.Web.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Extensions, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.UI, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.UI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Web, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Wizard, Version=16.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.Wizard.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="getBeckhoffTpy, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4481a3cada349683, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\getBeckhoffTpy.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.CSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Npgsql, Version=3.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\Npgsql.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
 <Reference Include="TwinCAT.Ads, Version=4.2.163.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=180016cd49e5e8c3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\TwinCAT.Ads.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MyWebVisuDlls.1.0.5\lib\net45\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Usually, `MyWebVisuDlls` package has many dependencies. And using packages.config needs to list them which may be a little trouble.

**In short**, I recommend the first way to use PackageReference which is a easy way to realize it.

Hope it could help you.