# How do you get NuGet package restore to work on locally deployed packages stored in VSIX targeting Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, vsix, vsixmanifest

I am aware there are multiple questions on this topic already, but they all seem outdated. To clarify, I am using the "new" VSIX manifest format, and trying to follow the official instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/visual-studio-templates

I have one project template and a couple of item templates that go with it. They all depend on deploying a NuGet package that should come bundled locally with the VSIX. I have examined the resulting VSIX file and all the files seem to be in the right place:

1. The project template has the required XML for declaring which packages to install:

```xml
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages repository="extension" repositoryId="VsixID.etc.etc">
      <package id="Rx-Linq" version="2.2.5" />
    </packages>
  </WizardData>
```

2. The `repositoryID` matches the `ID` attribute in the `.vsixmanifest` file.
3. There is an individual `Asset` entry for each package, with the form:

```xml
    <Asset Type="Rx-Linq.2.2.5.nupkg" d:Source="File" Path="Packages\Rx-Linq.2.2.5.nupkg" d:VsixSubPath="Packages" />
```

4. I have removed all `packages.config` and all the package references from the `.csproj` file installed by the VSIX (and even from the VSIX project itself just for good measure).
5. I have inspected the output VSIX and there is indeed a `Packages` folder in the VSIX containing all the `.nupkg` files. This folder is indeed unpacked and copied into the Visual Studio `Extensions` folder.

Despite all this, when I create a new project with the template, VS displays an error message saying: Failed to restore package from `C:\users\<pathtoextensions>\Packages`.

The thing is, the `.nupkg` files are actually present in the exact folder that the error message refers to.

I have been searching this for days and I can't seem to find any reference to best practices that actually work. It seems like these VSIX manifests are geared towards the legacy `packages.config` way of doing things, and there are discussions about how to extend them to use `PackageReference` instead.

Can anyone give any advice at all at how we are supposed to proceed going forward? Are packages not supposed to be deployed with the VSIX anymore? Are we supposed to just fill in the project with `PackageReference` entries and just let the user resolve them manually?

I feel like I am missing something fundamental here and any insight would be extremely valuable.

**Update:** I have also opened an [issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9387) on the NuGet github repository, as this is clearly a problem with the PackageRestore feature when restoring packages stored in a VSIX installer. Everything else mentioned in this question is working as intended and expected, except the package restore.

Answer (score -1):

> How do you actually include NuGet packages in Visual Studio Project
>   Templates VSIX targeting Visual Studio 2019?

**Actually**, there is no way to specify in a VS project template project that nuget packages can be used both using `packages.config` and `PackageReference`. Only two project templates of nuget management types can be created separately.

I have an easy way and since you have some issues with `PackageReference` format, you can try this funtion:

**PackageReference**

**1)** add these reference node in projecttemplate.csporj file:

[image]

```
   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Rx-Linq">
      <Version>2.2.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**2)** When you create a project by this project template, please check these two options and VS will automatically read `xxx.csproj` and then recover the corresponding nuget package based on the information in it during build process.

[image]

**Note**: also make sure that the nuget url is checked and can be access under Package Source.

**packages.config**

**In additon**, for `packages.config`, you can just create a file named `packages.config` and then add your nuget info into it:

**1)**

**2)** add these into `projecttemplate.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="packages.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Rx-Linq, Version=2.2.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-Linq.2.2.5\lib\net472\xxxxxxx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Note**: if this nuget package has dependencies, you should also add them(above steps) into `packages.config` and `xxxx.csproj` file. This funcution is a little more complicated than yours but it works. So, I recommend that you use `PackageReference` format.

More info you can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269499/vs2017-vstemplate-automatically-install-nuget-package/59306642#59306642).

Comment: It is quite possible to include package references which are compatible both with `packages.config` and `PackageReference`. In fact, you do it exactly as I pointed out in the question. The only problem is that NuGet VS will not find packages that are only included in the VSIX. As long as they are available online, it will be fine. I have edited the question to include the issue I opened in the nuget github repository.